# Getting peanut butter out with the back of a spoon

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, idioms, vocabulary

I like wiping the back of a spoon on peanut butter to get it out of the jar, instead of scooping it out the normal way. Could this action still be described as “scooping out”, but with the back of the spoon?
What about “pulling out peanut butter with the back of a spoon”? Does that sound right?

Comment: *Could this action still be described as “scooping out”,* No. A scoop is any instrument with a hollowed inner, and *to scoop* requires the hollow attribute. Your action is so rare that it would have to be described in full. Fortunately, you have done that. I would say *"I like getting the peanut butter out of the jar with the back of a spoon."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The verb for this, which doesn't specify the part of the utensil used, is actually [**spoon**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spoon):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> *transitive*
> : to take up and usually transfer in a spoon

Used in your example:

> I *spooned* peanut butter out of the jar.

What's good about this verb is that it doesn't matter *how* you used the spoon, only that you did.

---

However, if you *do* want to specify the exact method, you could simply add the description.

- Assuming you don't mind the repetitive use of the word:
  I spooned out peanut butter *with the back of a spoon*.
- If you don't like the repetition, you can do what I did at the start of this answer:
  I spooned out peanut butter *with back of the utensil*.

---

To address a comment that the Merriam-Webster definition cannot be interpreted as functional with the *back* of a spoon, because it uses the preposition *in*, here is the [Oxford (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spoon) definition of the verb:

> **1** *[with object and adverbial of direction]* Put (food) into or on something with a spoon.
> ‘Rosie spooned sugar into her mug’

Note how it uses the preposition *with* rather than *in*.

As such, I don't hold to the inference that *spoon* necessitates a specific usage.

Comment: The definition you quoted does specify the part of the utensil, it says "transfer *in* a spoon" - peanut butter on the back of the spoon is not *in* the spoon.  But still I agree this is the best verb for the OP's case.

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: For me, the repetition of *I spooned out peanut butter with the back of a spoon.* is unforgiveable. And in *I spooned out peanut butter with back of the utensil* ."the utensil" is far from idiomatic and would make me think that "the utensil" was a previously mentioned item, rather than the spoon.